# Kohana 3 ORM find_all() returns all rows regardless of where clause

Tags: kohana-3, kohana-orm

I have one simple `users` table, and I want to find all users where `email_notifications` = 1.

Logic dictates that the following should work:

```
class Controller_Test extends Controller {

    public function action_index()
    {
        $user = ORM::factory('user');
        $user = $user->where('email_notifications', '=', 1);
        $total = $user->count_all();
        $users = $user->find_all();

        echo $total." records found.<br/>";

        foreach ($users as $v)
        {
            echo $v->id;
            echo $v->first_name;
            echo $v->last_name;
            echo $v->email;
        }
    }
}
```

However, what's happening is that I am getting ALL of my users back from the DB, not just the ones with email_notifications turned on. The funny thing is, the `$total` value returned is the accurate number result of this query.

I am so stumped, I have no idea what the problem is here.  If anyone could shed some light, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Calling `count_all()` will reset your model conditions. Try to use `reset(FALSE)` to avoid this:

```
    $user = ORM::factory('user');
    $user = $user->where('email_notifications', '=', 1);
    $user->reset(FALSE); 
    $total = $user->count_all();
    $users = $user->find_all();
```

Comment: That was it! It figures it would be something that simple, lol. Do you happen to have a reference that I could look at that talks about this particular issue? There's nothing on Kohana's site...

Comment: Just read a source code. There was a `count_last_query()` function in previous versions, so I tried to find an alternate method.